# How to seque to ViewController inside Navigation Controller inside TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

This is a totally dumb question I am sure. I have a viewcontroller that is inside a navigation controller that is inside a TabBarController. Apple says this is the right way to implement that setup. However, how can I prepareForSeque to that complex and send data to the first ViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "presentActionItems" {
        println("preparing")
        let tabBarController:actionItemsTabController = segue.destinationViewController as! actionItemsTabController

        let navigationController = ???
        let viewController = ???

        viewController.givenURL = actionItemsURL
    }
}
```

I am sure this is an easy question, can I have some help.

Comment: I usually pass my data to the tab controller, then you can pass it to whichever of your tab views you'd like

Comment: so I prepareForSeque in the tab controller too?

Comment: my destination is also inside a navigationController that is inside a tabBar to try to be clear.

Comment: Yeah the tabcontroller has a reference to all of the view controllers it holds, so in the viewDidLoad you can then pass on the data to the proper view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your TabController's viewDidLoad after passing it your data

```
let firstViewController : UIViewController = self.viewControllers.objectAtIndex(0).topViewController;
firstViewController.this = self.this;
firstViewController.that = self.that;
```

Comment: You may need to cast the `objectAtIndex(0)` to a `UINavigationController`